# Compare time in 24 hour format in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare two time in 24 hour format.

Like for example, compare 03:00 with 18:00 which is greater.

So far, I tried below coding but fail:

```
comboBox1.Text = '03:00';
comboBox2.Text = '18:00';
t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBox1.Text);
t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBox2.Text);
CmpTm = DateTime.Compare(t1, t2);
```

It fail because to use 'Convert.ToDateTime' it need Date also. But I don't want it to compare date, I just want it to compare time in 24 hour format. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Danny, I just want to compare time. No date involve.

Comment: EXACTLY! Re-read the title.

Comment: You could also consider using a DateTimePicker control with dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time.

Comment: I tried the coding, my input is incorrect because I don't have the date.

Comment: Just edit
`comboBox1.Text = "03:00:00.000";
comboBox2.Text = "18:00:00.000";`
and you are good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to compare dates/seconds parts of times (not regarding the fact that the outcome is the same), just the hour-minute-parts, convert it to an int and compare them:

```
comboBox1.Text = "03:00";
comboBox2.Text = "18:00";
int t1 = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.Text.Replace(":", ""));
int t2 = Int32.Parse(comboBox2.Text.Replace(":", ""));
var comp = t1 == t2 ? 0 : (t1 < t2 ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Int32 don't have 'Compare' function..

Answer (score 4):

Use timespans instead, why using DateTime if you are only comparing Times not Dates

```
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("3:00", "HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var time2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("18:00", "HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

CmpTm = TimeSpan.Compare(time, time2);
```

Comment: But I don't want compare the second, just hour and minute..how?

Comment: @Coolguy so use ParseExact like I do in edited answer. Now I'm parsing hours and minutes from string

Answer (score 1):

Parse the strings into a `DateTime` object and compare those.

```
var t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox1.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var t2 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox2.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

CmpTm = DateTime.Compare(t1, t2);
```

Comment: I got error regarding CultureInfo. Why?

Comment: @Coolguy add `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you are using `''` instead of `""` when you define strings.

When you use [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with only hours and minutes, it will convert to today dates, hours, minutes etc..

Here a working example;

```
string s = "03:00";
string s1 = "18:00";
var t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(s); // t1 will be 06/12/2013 03:00:00
var t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(s1); //t2 will be 06/12/2013 18:00:00
var CmpTm = DateTime.Compare(t1, t2); //CmpTm  will be -1
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Kp9mTo)</kbd>.

Comment: But I don;t want to compare date. I compare only hour and minute. How?

Comment: @Coolguy With this way, you actually comparing hours because they have same day, month and year part..

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deal with time intervals.
This class provides [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/se73z7b9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to convert string to timespan

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing them in a defined format:

```
comboBox1.Text = "03:00";
comboBox2.Text = "18:00";
t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox1, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
t2 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox2, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
CmpTm = DateTime.Compare(t1, t2);
```

Comment: are you sure that it compile?

Comment: I got error regarding CultureInfo.

Comment: Don't forget to import System.Globalization, and as pointed out above, the strings should be defined using " instead of ', that's an error from copy pasting the original post

Comment: I don't think c# support "multiple char chars" :) <- it's a clue

Comment: @Coolguy: you might be missing reference  try : `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox1.Text = "03:00";
comboBox2.Text = "18:00";
t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox1.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
t2 = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox2.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var Compare =TimeSpan.Compare(t1.TimeOfDay, t2.TimeOfDay);
```

Check [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) and [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare.aspx)

```
`Value`          `Description`


  -1            t1 is shorter than t2.

   0            t1 is equal to t2.

   1            t1 is longer than t2.
```